# How to add an index on ASUSTOR NAS for filename searching?

Tags: nas, asus, asustor

I am looking for how to let my Mac (or PC) look into a folder on ASUSTOR NAS and then search for any file that has the word "Cat" in its filename, for example. (probably by SMB but other ways are ok).

It'd be ok to search by real time but better yet, by an index already built.  My Synology is enabled for this right out of the box and I wonder why ASUS made it so difficult to configure. Isn't it the whole point of NAS?

I can go to the Terminal on the Mac and use Bash, and type in

```bash
find /Volumes/Public -iname '*cat*'
```

but that's a real time search and it is slow, and it is troublesome to do it in a text based command prompt.

I looked into the manual and there is no mentioning of "index" and searching on Internet says use "Searchlight" in the ADM, but that seems like I have to go to the Web browser, log into the NAS, and then search inside there. I want to be able to search right inside of Windows or Mac's Finder.

With my Synology NAS, it is possible right out of the box. With my Western Digital NAS, the search results came back slow so it looks like it is real time search, but at least I get the results. On Asustor, I simply do not get any result whatsoever.

I am using the latest ADM version 4.0.6.REG2.